# Is newsstand framework required for creating newsstand app?

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

This question may seem strange, but still would like to clarify for myself. Is Newsstand framework required to use in newsstand app? I mean, can I make own issue model instead of `NKIssue`, download issues with `ASIHTTPRequest` instead of `NKAssetDownload` and so on? Or my app will be rejected by Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could make such an app, but I'm not so sure Apple would agree making it a Newsstand app. There are some things that may or may not be possible to duplicate (like silent push notifications for iOS < 7) but they are minor, depending on what you are after.

If you have it as a stand-alone app it should be ok, but then again maybe Apple will ask you to put it in Newsstand if it's a magazine-style app.

So the answer is, you are better off contacting Apple support to know for sure before starting your project...